# Efficiently identifying if any item in first set matches any item in second set

Tags: linq, .net-4.0

I have two `IEnumerable<string>` that represent lists of strings. I want to see if any element in the first set matches any element in the second set. At the moment I have something that looks like this:

```
firstSet.Intersect(secondSet).Count() > 0
```

However, it seems to me to be rather inefficient because it will produce a list of the elements that match, then count them all. I can then test to see if the count is greater than zero. I don't care about which match, how many match, just that any element in the two sets match. Is there anything like `firstSet.AnyMatch(secondSet)` that I'm missing?

Is there a more efficient way to express that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Any` instead:

```
if (firstSet.Intersect(secondSet).Any())
```

I believe this will build of hash set of the *second* collection first (in its entirety) and then iterate over the first set until it finds a match or runs out of elements to test. You may wish to bear this in mind when working out which way round to put `firstSet` and `secondSet`.

EDIT: Just to repeat what's already in a comment... if you know that (say) `firstSet` is a `HashSet<string>` then you should cast to it and use [`Overlaps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355623%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

```
HashSet<string> firstHashSet = (HashSet<string>) firstSet;
if (firstHashSet.Overlaps(secondSet))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that if the underlying type was a HashSet<T> already that it wouldn't rebuild it?

Comment: @Colin: I'm not sure whether it's optimized for that. If you *know* that one of them is a `HashSet<string>` then you should cast to that and call `HashSet<T>.Overlaps`.